# C# & Word: How to stop Undo tracing in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

How can I stop the Undo tracing in Word from C#?

I need to stop it because I do a lot of things in the document via C# and I don't want the users view these things doing Undo!

I do not want to clear ALL the Undo cache, I would stop in a certain time and restart after some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer. Great Cindy :-)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/02a1a304-3090-4e4d-826e-96c8ad2e7806